# How to set button tag for DLRadioButton ? - iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using DLRadioButton. I want to implement some calculation when user click the radio buttons. How to include the IF ELSE statement with the button tag? Below are part of my codes, but it fails.

```
- (void)calculation 
{ 
  DLRadioButton *button = [[DLRadioButton alloc] init]; 
  double purchasePrice = [self.purchasePrice.text doubleValue]; 
  double priceLabel = [self.priceLabel.text doubleValue]; 

  self.firstBtn.tag = 0; 
  self.secondBtn.tag = 1; 

  if (button.tag == 0) 
  { 
    priceLabel = purchasePrice * 2; 
    self.priceLabel.text=[NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel]; 
  } 
  else if (button.tag == 1) 
  { 
    priceLabel = purchasePrice * 3; 
    self.priceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel]; 
  }
}

- (void)calculateButton
{
  [self calculation];
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the tag to self.firstBtn and self.secondBtn but you are comparing the value of a tag for the instance of DLRadioButton without assigning a tag value to it.

Comment: I want to do this - When I select firstBtn, it will perform a calculation. When I select secondBtn, it will perform another calculation.

Comment: self.firstBtn what is where declared this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculation as per tag value you need to set tag first .

```
UIButton *firstBtn,*secondButton; // crate instance of buttons
```

Declare selector method in viewDidLaod

```
    [firstBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(calculation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    firstBtn.tag = 0;
    [secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(calculation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    secondButton.tag = 1;
```

Action bethod buttons :

```
- (void)calculation:(UIButton *)sender{
    if (sender.tag == 0)
    {
        priceLabel = purchasePrice * 2;
        self.priceLabel.text=[NSString
                              stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel];
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 1)
    {
        priceLabel = purchasePrice * 3;
        self.priceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",priceLabel];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome... @Winter